# How to format Date with time zone in pattern string in java.time?

Tags: java, timezone, java-8

I have a string pattern for a formatter

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z
```

How to parse a java.util.Date using this pattern?

The problem is the time zone already in this pattern.

```
String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";

DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT).format(date.toInstant());
```

This apparently gives

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: YearOfEra
    at java.time.Instant.getLong(Instant.java:603)
    at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:298)
```

The solutions here and in other places doesn't have timezone in the format string and offer solutions like:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(dateD.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()))
```

Can I somehow parse it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [`Instant` does not have the notion of year of era](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#isSupported-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-):

> The supported fields are:
>
> - NANO_OF_SECOND
> - MICRO_OF_SECOND
> - MILLI_OF_SECOND
> - INSTANT_SECONDS

You could use a ZonedDateTime instead:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
String format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT).format(zdt);
```